# Trying to add file to component state isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been messing with this for too long now, and I can't figure out why the file isn't being added to the local state. Here's the code:

```
onFileSelect(event){
  console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  let name = event.target.files[0].name;
  let photoObject = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(photoObject);
  this.setState({ photoName: name, photo: photoObject }, function () {
    console.log('from state:' + JSON.stringify(this.state.photo));
    console.log('state is; ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
  });
}
```

And here's the file input:

```
<div className="custom-file">
  <input
    type="file"
    className="custom-file-input"
    onChange={this.onFileSelect}
    id="customFile"
  />
  <label className="custom-file-label" for="customFile">
    {this.state.photoName}
  </label>
</div>
```

In the console.log's in the callback for setState, I get :

> from state:{}
>
> state is; {"yardName":"Please","yardLat":"","yardLng":"","yardType":"General","photoName":"splash.jpg","photo":{},"errors":{}}

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It _is_ being added - you just can't stringify the file in the state. If you simply do `console.log(this.state)` the following will be logged: `Object { photoName: "Duvf1wAWsAE8XMT.jpg", photo: File }`. [The file is there](https://jsfiddle.net/u6vx04jb/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you misused `this`.

```js
this.setState({photoName:name,photo:photoObject},
function(){
   console.log('from state:' + JSON.stringify(this.state.photo));
   console.log('state is; ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
})
```

In console.log function, the `this` means the function itself. So you should use arrow function like below

```js
this.setState({photoName:name,photo:photoObject},
() => {
   console.log('from state:' + JSON.stringify(this.state.photo));
   console.log('state is; ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

since the setState callback function in your code is regular function you can’t have this available inside it so as @Conan Lee mentioned either you need to change it to Arrow function or bind the function to have this context available to access updated state

Bind the function using .bind(this) like below

```
    onFileSelect(event){
       console.log(event.target.files[0]);
       let name = event.target.files[0].name;
       let photoObject = event.target.files[0];
      console.log(photoObject);
      this.setState({ photoName: name, photo: photoObject     }, function () {
     console.log('from state:' +    JSON.stringify(this.state.photo));
     console.log('state is; ' + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }.bind(this)}
 }
```